# Mongo group by date which is actually a string data type

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Is there a way to aggregate a string as date. ?

My field looks like this. It's not a date field but a string.

`CreatedDate => "2014-11-24T11:14:51.000+0000`

Now I want to group(Moped Query)

`{ "$group" => { _id: { day: { "$dayOfMonth" => "$CreatedDate"}, month: {"$month" => "$CreatedDate"}, year: { "$year" => "$CreatedDate" } }`

I get the following error when I run the query.

`"exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date"`

P.S:

Converting this field from string to date is my last option.

So, is there any other way to aggregate a string field?

Answer (score 2):

Hi If assuming below conditions

1> `month` starts with 0 for ex: if month Feb. then it will be `02`

2> `day` start with 0 for ex: if day below <= 9 will be start 01, 02,...,09 etc

then below aggregation work without changing data type string to ISODate

```
    db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": {
                "$substr": ["$CreatedDate", 0, 4]
            },
            "month": {
                "$substr": ["$CreatedDate", 5, 2]
            },
            "day": {
                "$substr": ["$CreatedDate", 8, 2]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

If above  assumption not possible then follow **Manjunath H** answer like first convert string to ISODate and then grouping.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert from string to date type in mongodb
than use [Aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) function to display `day`, `month` and `year`

`collection name: testdata`  which contain

```
myDevReplSet:PRIMARY> db.testdata.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54edbd94e84aac1464560025"), "CreatedDate" : "2014-11-24T11:14:51.000+0000" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54edbd9fe84aac1464560026"), "CreatedDate" : "2014-12-06T11:14:51.000+0000" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54edbdabe84aac1464560027"), "CreatedDate" : "2014-07-05T11:14:51.000+0000" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54edbdb8e84aac1464560028"), "CreatedDate" : "2014-08-15T11:14:51.000+0000" }
```

Use below code to Convert `CreatedDate`field from String into [ISODate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/)

```
myDevReplSet:PRIMARY>db.testdata.find().forEach(function(element){
  element.CreatedDate = ISODate(element.CreatedDate);
  db.testdata.save(element);
})
```

`testdata` collection look like below

```
myDevReplSet:PRIMARY> db.testdata.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54edbd94e84aac1464560025"), "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2014-11-24T11:14:51Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54edbd9fe84aac1464560026"), "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2014-12-06T11:14:51Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54edbdabe84aac1464560027"), "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2014-07-05T11:14:51Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54edbdb8e84aac1464560028"), "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2014-08-15T11:14:51Z") }
```

To display day, month and year using mongodb aggregate function

```
db.testdata.aggregate([
                   { 
                       "$group" : { _id: { 
                                           day: { "$dayOfMonth" : "$CreatedDate"}, 
                                           month: {"$month" : "$CreatedDate"}, 
                                           year: { "$year" : "$CreatedDate"} 
                                      } } }
                 ]                    
               )
```

**Result:**

```
{ "_id" : { "day" : 15, "month" : 8, "year" : 2014 } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 5, "month" : 7, "year" : 2014 } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 6, "month" : 12, "year" : 2014 } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 24, "month" : 11, "year" : 2014 } }
```

Hope it helps.